# Across different timeframes with candlestick patterns

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have searched and there is no post covered with this topic.

I have the script to find patterns working.

What function in pinescript allows you to search for patterns across 15 min , 5 min , 3 min time frames happening at the same time?

So if a pattern is triggered off in 5 min time frames how does one program to look within the two 5 min candles to see if another pattern is found in a 3 min time frame?

Is there any limit to the number of timeframes one can search into? e.g. 15min, 5 min, 3 min or 15min and 5 min.

How does one program different combinations so for example above the alert is still issued with any two combinations of the three timeframes?

Can the request.security be used to find candlestick patterns going back in time 15min, 5 min, 3min for the symbol the alert is set on?

request.security(symbol, timeframe, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol, currency) → series float

This is the search pattern query that works:-

````
Three_White_Soldiers = (green_candle_2_days_ago and green_candle_1_day_ago and green_candle_today)
and (high_2_days_ago <= close_1_day_ago and high_1_day_ago <= close_today)
and (close_2_days_ago >= open_1_day_ago and close_1_day_ago >= open_today)
and (open_2_days_ago <= low_1_day_ago and open_1_day_ago <= low_today)```

Regards
````

Comment: you can send your function into request.security in a limit of 40 security calls in a script.. so request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'15',Three_White_Soldiers)  assuming Three_White_Soldiers is written properly.. and if it returns bool true/false, security will as well

Comment: John yes the Three_White_Soldiers and does return a true / false - I have tested it with that statement.

Comment: request.security(syminfo.tickerid,'15',Three_White_Soldiers) - this tests the 15 min timeframe - how does this include Three_White_Soldiers the lower timeframes like 5 min and also 3 min?

Comment: Would you need to use a array in this situation?

Comment: security_lower_tf() returns an array of values from the chart of the lower timeframes - so what would the code be to make this all work?

Comment: for example if you are on 15min chart, and u use security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid,'5', Three_White_Soldiers)  you would get an array of size 3, each element would provide true/false, each would be 5min of the 15min chart u r viewing. to get the first 5min, array.get(return_array,0).. 1 for 2nd , 2 for 3rd..

Comment: Then from the array you would do if then statements to confirm outputs which will then be connect to alerts been issued?

Comment: yes you could do that

Comment: John are there any other ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: i think if you want to go after lower tf this is the most reliable way to do it - some folks have used request.security but the results are unreliable

Comment: John have you done this coding / project already?

Comment: i am sorry, what project? have i used lower_tf security? yes

Comment: John did you have trouble with when the bigger Timeframe pattern triggers, having an issue to find ways to fetch the past data candles to check if a pattern happened previously in the lower time frames. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can mark the pattern on your chart when both timeframes happen and see visually if it occurred.

Comment: Mark the chart with what ? Did you have a issue of not been able to get past data of patterns that have formed?

Comment: past data in lower time frame is limited. There is a blog post about this on tradingview, how much data is available for each time frame

Comment: John I am only needing 15 min to 45 min of data on the day. Surely this is not a issue with lower_tf security function?

Comment: it is not an issue, so then what is the issue of it not displaying? is this a strategy or an indicator? is it calculating on a daily chart? if strategy then is it set to calc on tick? more questions that would be answered by looking at the script

Comment: Hi John thanks for your input. Used loops and arrays to get around the problem. Cheers